# Sending and receiving an array to a sql database via JSON

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, gson

I put an array in an object which is send to an java webservice (see javascript.js -> sendDataToWebservice()). The webservice proceeds the array  (via gson) and saves it as a String in an sql database (see webservice.java -> handleDataFunction()). When I want to receive the array the data is not properly converted back to an array (see javascript.js -> receiveDataFromWebservice()). Instead of an array the data will be converted to an String like this: "["item1", "item2]".

Do I need to parse the array? I think the problem is that somewhere in between there are added the quotation marks and thus the data is recognized as a string and not an array.

Thanks in advance!

javascript.js

```
var myArray = new Array();

function sendDataToWebservice() {
    // Create the JSON to send to the webservice
    var jsonData = {
        "action": actionName,
        "array": myArray
    };

    // Send the data
    $.ajax({
        url: "/xaction/",
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}

function reveiveDataFromWebservice() {
    // Receive the data
    jQuery.getJSON("/webservice/getdata", function (returningData) {
        if (returningData.success) {
            array= returningData.array;
            }
    });
```

webservice.java

```
private void handleDataFunction(inputData) {
    // Create a map for the parameters
    MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    // Create the query string
    String query = "my sql query";
    // Here I want to retrievethe array as a String to store it in the db
    JsonArray jsonArray = currentAntwortFeld.get("array").getAsJsonArray();
    // Add the array as an String to the sql parameters
    namedParameters.addValue("arraydbfield", jsonArray.toString())
    // Execute the sql query
    factory.executeUpdate(query, namedParameters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() will turn a string containing an array into an array object.

```
myArray = JSON.parse(myString)
```

Can't tell why jQuery isn't already doing that for you though. I thought that was the point of `$.getJSON()`. But I don't use jQuery, so I don't really know.

Comment: I tried using myArray = JSON.parse(myString) but I am only getting an SyntaxError (Unexptected token o in JSON at position 1)

Comment: That means the string you are generating on the server is an incorrect representation of a javascript array. Try printing it out on the server side and look for errors to hopefully dig out the bug. Once you send a properly formatted array string, jQuery will probably do the parsing for you. I think it's generating a string because that's the only way it can give you something valid instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

For converting from JSON to SQL I implemented as follows:

```
 let jsArray = [1,2,3,4] //Example array in JS
 let sqlArray = '{';
 jsArray.forEach(element=>sqlArray+=element+',')
 sqlArray = sqlArray.substring(0, sqlArray.length-1) + '}'
```

Now use sqlArray is fit for SQL.